# Sqlite SELECT * for Last 30 days

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite DB with the following columns:

File, Date_created, Owner

How do I get the list of files created in the last 30 days?

I tried the following, but it didn't limit the result. The list came back with files created 2 years ago!

`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Date_created > (SELECT DATETIME('now', '-30 day'))`

Also, not sure if it matters, but my Created_date column is in the following date format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: Change the format to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQLite doesn't have a native datetime data type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so that comparison's going to be on text. If your records are in DD/MM/YYYY format, you'll end up with comparisons like `"07/03/2020" > "2020-06-07"` which make little sense.

If you opt to store your datetimes as text, you must use a format that's lexicographically orderable. A great standard format that exhibits this property (if every piece of data has the same timezone, anyway) is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), e.g. `2020-07-07 15:04:14+0300` at the time of writing in my timezone. As an aside, [even xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1179/) recommends ISO 8601.

If you opt to store your datetimes as numbers, you can store them as either [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), or maybe, if you're feeling adventurous, as e.g. the number `20200707150414`. Do remember neither of these numeric options store timezone information, if that's important to your application.

As an aside,

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Date_created > DATETIME('now', '-30 day')
```

is enough :)

Comment: Thanks mate, you are right, my date is in text so I'll have to look into a way to rework the format. Thanks for the info. So if I make that format change, that SELECT query will work?

Comment: Just confirming it now works. Thanks for your help and insight.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you are looking for, it's something that's come up in my head, haven't tested it.

Basically you're going 30 days backwards by Date_created.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()), Date_created) > 0
```

Comment: SQLite does not support DATEDIFF(), GETDATE() and DATEADD() functions.